# Chrome Extension - Running JS script with hotkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a simple extension to do the following:

When I open a certain website, e.g. example.com, and then press a certain hotkey (Ctrl + Space), the page should scroll to a certain vertical position (e.g. 500px).

Here is the code I currently have:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Scroll",
"description" : "Scroll",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
}],
"commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Space"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**script.js**

```
window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```

When I test it, the page scrolls to 500px once it is opened. But I want it to scroll only when I press the hotkey. I checked some tutorials but couldn't figure out what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Revised files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Scroll",
    "description" : "Scroll.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["script.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "commands": {
        "scroll": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Space"
            },
            "description": "Scroll"
        }
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command == "scroll") {
        // alert("Test"); this works
        window.scrollTo(0, 500); // this doesn't work
    }
});
```

It displays the alert when I test it, but it doesn't perform the scroll.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is background script.

**Background scripts** are something that run in background and listen for triggers while the user interacts with the chrome browser (such as listening for a click event on a tab or in your case listening for keystrokes).

Your scroll code is in **Content Script** which will always run when the page loads. Hence the behaviour you see.

In your background script, you can write the code for scroll. So it will only scroll if keystrokes are seen.

This shall help you even more: [Background Pages in Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT: Try this:

```
"commands": {
    "scroll" : {
        "suggested_key": {
             "default": "Ctrl+Space" 
        },
        "description": "Scroll Function"
    }    
}
```

Put the above code in your `manifest.json`.

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command === "scroll") {
        alert("scrolled");
    }
});
```

Put this code in your `background.js`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I saw some examples using content scripts that's why I used a content script. I tried replacing content_scripts section in my code with "background": { "scripts": ["script.js"] }, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: To catch keypress events, you will have to use a `content script` that sends messages to the `background page`. The `content script` is injected to the open web page and insert methods for catching keypresses, and then send a message to the `background page` with information on which keys are pressed. Here, you can write your action of scroll.

Comment: Thanks, I had checked that page. My issue with Google's documentations (for any topic really) is that they are, in my opinion, not written from a beginner perspective. It is difficult to bring together code pieces into a working result. I edited my question with revised files based on your code sample, the alert is not displayed when I press the hotkey.

Comment: Try this keys: Ctrl+Shift+Y. And then see if it detects.

Comment: It looks I needed to do a crucial thing: To go to "chrome://extensions/", and set the hotkey manually under "Keyboard shortcuts". After doing that, alert("scrolled") works fine, but window.scrollTo(0, 500) doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: If the alert worked, assuming the next line is `window.scrollTo(0, 500)`, it should've worked. Or else I'm out of fuel.

Comment: I updated my question with the final revision of files. I feel I am very close. Thank you very much for your help.